# No Images Found in Gallery

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-gallery

I need to test a function that needs to picks some images from the gallery of Android JellyBean Emulator.

So I have downloaded from internet using the own browser of the emulator (that is slow as the hell) some images.

The images appears in the downloaded files but not in the Gallery of Emulator.

In the GingerBread emulator when I download an images from the browser these appear automatically in the gallery.

How could I force the emulator to find the images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the old emulator the media scanner was enabled, due to large amount of resource needed the new version has the media scanner disabled by default.

If you want to see the images in the gallery,
in the main menu of Jelly Bean Emulator go in:

DevTools->Media Provider and click *"Scan SD Card"*.

In this way you should see the images in the gallery

If doesn't, probably the images saved aren't properly located in SD card,

-use DDMS(you can find it in the Android\android-sdk\tools folder

-Click on device menu and select File Explorer

-Go to mnt\sdcard

-Click the button "Push file into device" to upload images

Answer (score 0):

If I correct, you want some pictures in emulator's gallery. I think you can upload a picture file in DDMS file browser, or using 'adb push' command.

Comment: could you give me more details? Where is the file DDMS browser?