# Image not displayed in Emulator's gallery

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've tried a file transfer program in Android. It works perfectly. The image is shown in `DDMS` , it is also shown in the `shell`, but it is not being displayed in the gallery of the emulator. Any ideas as to where the issue might be? To clarify - I'm not asking how to push a file into the emulator.

Here are the snapshots to confirm the same :
[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**
I've even tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003533/828625 . But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Could you move the images to /mnt/sdcard and then try the mediaScanner ? Instead of /mnt/sdcard/saved_images. You could also move it under /mnt/sdcard/Pictures. To create that you could run :

```
adb mkdir /Pictures
```

from the /sdcard directory